# Bad substitution error for running a bash command for many files in a folder in for loop

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

I have some files (image-1.nii, image2.nii, etc.) in a folder (`INPUT_DIRECTORY`) which are inputs to a command, and the result files should be saved in two other directories (`BIAS_DIRECTORY`,`SEGMENTATION_N4_IMAGES`).

These are the command that I tried to write:

```
 #!/bin/bash

INPUT_DIRECTORY=${PWD}/Images
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${PWD}/Output
BIAS_DIRECTORY=${PWD}/BIAS
SEGMENTATION_N4_IMAGES=${PWD}/N4

mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
mkdir -p $BIAS_DIRECTORY
mkdir -p $SEGMENTATION_N4_IMAGES

N4=${ANTSPATH}/N4BiasFieldCorrection
N4_CONVERGENCE="[100x100x100x100,0.0000000001]"
N4_SHRINK_FACTOR=2
N4_BSPLINE_PARAMS="[200]"
DIMENSION=3

NIIEXT=".nii"
NIIFILES="($INPUT_DIRECTORY/*$NIIEXT)"

for FILE in "${NIIFILES[@]}"; do
    FILENAME="$(basename $FILE $NIIEXT)"
    ${N4} -d ${DIMENSION} -i ${FILENAME}.nii -s ${N4_SHRINK_FACTOR} -c ${N4_CONVERGENCE} -b ${N4_BSPLINE_PARAMS} -o ["(${SEGMENTATION_N4_IMAGES}/${FILENAME})".nii,"(${BIAS_DIRECTORY}/${FILENAME})".nii.gz] --verbose 1

done
```

I am getting error for this line `for FILE in "${NIIFILES[@]}"; do` (error:`Bad substitution`) and I am not sure whether my code is correct or not. Could experts please have a look? Thanks

Comment: `NIIFILES=("$INPUTDIRECTORY"/*"$NIIEXT")` -- the way you wrote the assignment `NIIFILES` is a string, and you want it to be an array.

Comment: Sidenote: the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) needs to be the first character of the file. If there is a space before it, it won't work, though in this case the script may be run by Bash anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @oliv's response, you need to declare it as an array. A safer way to declare it as an array is this:

```
declare -a NIIFILES=( "$INPUT_DIRECTORY"/*.nii )
```

It gives slightly more control over the content in that it marks it unquestionably as an array to the next developer to see it.

A more shorthand way, or if space may later become a problem (from too many files/folders in the tree) you could use:

```
for FILE in "INPUT_DIRECTORY"/*.nii; do
  FILENAME="$(basename $FILE $NIIEXT)"
  ${N4} -d ${DIMENSION} -i ${FILENAME}.nii -s ${N4_SHRINK_FACTOR} -c ${N4_CONVERGENCE} -b ${N4_BSPLINE_PARAMS} -o ["(${SEGMENTATION_N4_IMAGES}/${FILENAME})".nii,"(${BIAS_DIRECTORY}/${FILENAME})".nii.gz] --verbose 1
done
```

Of course, it's all up to preference. These and similar structures can be seen in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your `NIIFILES` is declared as a string and not as an array.

Assuming file don't have space in their filename, you could use:

```
NIIFILES=( "$INPUT_DIRECTORY"/*.nii )
```